# Angular5 - How to pass ASYNC data from parent to child component

Tags: angular, angular5, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to pass ASYNC data from parent to child component, I'm getting undefined message.

Because of ASYNC data, I suppose data coming from parent is not yet bound at OnInit.

In parent.component.html :

```
<my-child [childdata]="parentdata"></my-child>
```

In parent.component.ts :

```
interface SpotBB {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
...
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  parentdata: Observable<SpotBB[]>;
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.parentdata = this.spotsservice.getSpots();
    // Call a service - Data stored in Firestore
  }
```

In child.component.html :

```
<button (click)="mycheck()">TEST</button>
<div *ngFor="let spot of childdata | async" >    
    {{ spot.id }} --- {{ spot.name }}     <!-- Works fine -->
</div>
```

In child.component.ts :

```
interface SpotBB {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
...
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() childdata: Observable<SpotBB[]>;
  copydata: Observable<SpotBB[]>;
  ...
  mycheck() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.copydata));   // --> !!! undefined !!!
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.copydata = this.childdata;  // COPY DATA NOT WORKING
  }
```

Comment: have you tried by console in the child component's ngOnInit like this `console.log(this.childdate)`

Comment: First of all, `Observable` do not fetch data if you don't subscribe it. log the `this.childdata`  on OnInit. Let me know it is undefined or not.

Comment: console.log(this.childdate) (in OnInit) is undefined.

Comment: add *ngIf condition. <my-child *ngIf=" parentdata" [childdata]="parentdata"></my-child>. It will load child component after getting  value from parent component.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement several options to get it wokring:

*1.* Listen for changing @Input in your child component using `ngOnChanges`:

```
// child component
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() childdata;
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // on loading you can access childdata
    console.log(changes.childdata.currentValue);
  }
```

*2.* Using `set` in child component for `childdata`:

```
// child component
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  private _childdata;
  @Input() set childdata(value) {
    this._childdata = value;
  }


  // get method for childdata (for *nfFor in template)
  get childdata() {
    return this._childdata;
  }
```

*3.* Make child component available (if it is acceptable) only after `parentdata` will be available:

parent component html:

```
<my-child *ngIf="parentDataLoaded" [childdata]="parentdata"></my-child>
```

In parent.component.ts :

```
interface SpotBB {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
...
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  parentdata: Observable<SpotBB[]>;
  parentDataLoaded: false;
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.spotsservice.getSpots()
      .subscribe(res => {
         // here is your successful results
         this.parentdata = res;
         this.parentDataLoaded = true;
      });
  }
```

For all options, I'm guessing to subscribe to `getSpots`, receive `parentdata` in your parent component and assign to `this.parentdata`:

```
// parent component
ngOnInit() {
  this.spotsservice.getSpots()
    .subscribe(res => {
      // here is your successful results
      this.parentdata = res;
    });
 }

 // child component html
 // *ngIf needs only if listening for changing
 // of childdata in child component
 <div *ngIf="childdata">
   <div *ngFor="let spot of childdata" >    
    {{ spot.id }} --- {{ spot.name }}     <!-- Works fine -->
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
`@Input() childData` to `@Input() set childData` will work. This will get the **childData** to be **refreshed** **on change**.